# Laravel Voyager Breadcrumb subdomain issue

Tags: php, laravel, docker, breadcrumbs, voyager

I have a issue regarding breadcrumbs in Voyager. When the breadcrumb is displayed, it shows a seperate box for 'Http' and for the 'URL'.

Picture: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lKZU.jpg)

Comment: Did you find a fix? I have the same issue

Answer (score 3):

same problem here, do you have a reverse proxy handling the SSL in front of the app?

This is my case, and i fixed it at this way, publish navbar.blade.php and replace the php breadcumbs section:

```
@php
  $url = route('voyager.dashboard');
  $currentUrl = Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::url();
  $dashboardUrlPath = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
  $currentUrlPath = parse_url($currentUrl, PHP_URL_PATH);
  $segments = array_filter(explode('/', str_replace($dashboardUrlPath, '', $currentUrlPath)));
@endphp
```

Answer (score 2):

Part of the answer was done by @Daniel López and I'll give him credit for that but just saying *"publish navbar.blade.php and replace the php breadcumbs section"* can be misleading to someone new to Voyager.

The issue can be caused by how your web server handles SSL.

To solve the issue: You have to first override the **navbar.blade.php** which you can find in the path ***"{path-to-your-project}/vendor/tcg/voyager/resources/views/dashboard/"*** by copying it to your project views folder in ***"{path-to-your-project}/resources/views/vendor/voyager/dashboard/"***.

With notepad or any code editor, edit the copied navbar.blade.php file.
Search for "@section('breadcrumbs')" and replace a block of code from within that section.

Replace the following :

```
    @php
        $segments = array_filter(explode('/', str_replace(route('voyager.dashboard'), '', Request::url())));
        $url = route('voyager.dashboard');
    @endphp
```

with the following:

```
    @php
      $url = route('voyager.dashboard');
      $currentUrl = Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::url();
      $dashboardUrlPath = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
      $currentUrlPath = parse_url($currentUrl, PHP_URL_PATH);
      $segments = array_filter(explode('/', str_replace($dashboardUrlPath, '', $currentUrlPath)));
    @endphp
```